# Calculate average time difference between two datetime fields per day

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, datetime

I have a taxi database with two datetime fields 'BookedDateTime' and 'PickupDateTime'. The customer needs to know the average waiting time from the time the taxi was booked to the time the driver actually 'picked up' the customer.

There are a heap of rows in the database covering a couple of month's data.

The goal is to craft a query that shows me the daily average.

So a super simple example would be:

```
BookedDateTime           | PickupDateTime
2014-06-09 12:48:00.000    2014-06-09 12:45:00.000
2014-06-09 12:52:00.000    2014-06-09 12:58:00.000    
2014-06-10 20:23:00.000    2014-06-10 20:28:00.000
2014-06-10 22:13:00.000    2014-06-10 22:13:00.000
```

2014-06-09 ((-3 + 6) / 2) = average is 00:03:00.000 (3 mins)

2014-06-10 ((5 + 0) / 2) = average is 00:02:30.000 (2.5 mins)

Is this possible or do I need to do some number crunching in code (i.e. C#)?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how come the bookedtime is earlier than the pickuptime, i mean the first record of ur example

Comment: Booked time is when the passenger has specified they want to be picked up. Pickup Time is when the taxi driver actually arrived. So this means the PickupDateTime value could be positive or negative. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this will do :

```
select Convert(date, BookedDateTime) as Date, AVG(datediff(minute, BookedDateTime, PickupDateTime)) as AverageTime
    from tablename 
    group by Convert(date, BookedDateTime)  
    order by Convert(date, BookedDateTime)
```

Comment: Thanks. As for all the answers I am getting the following error which must be something to do with the data rather than the query: 'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.'

Comment: I think the error I am receiving is due to the following issue: "To calculate the mean average the server needs to be able to sum all of the ints first, so the datatype you are averaging on needs to able to store the sum of those values, even if the returned answer is within the range of of an int." There A LOT of rows per day meaning the number will easily be larger than an int. Is there any way of defaulting the calculation to use a bigint instead?

Comment: You can convert the expression to bigint before calling AVG : 

AVG(Convert(bigint, datediff(minute, BookedDateTime, PickupDateTime)))

Comment: Many thanks. You were the first response and this works perfectly for my needs. Therefore I have awarded this as the selected answer. The problems I was experiencing are due to some dates defaulting to 1970 when they were imported. Once I removed these from the data everything worked perfectly. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using the day of the booked time as the day for reporting:

```
select
    convert(date, BookedDateTime) as day,
    AVG(DATEDIFF(minute, PickupDateTime, BookedDateTime)) as avg_minutes
from bookings
group by convert(BookedDateTime, datetime, 101)
```

Comment: Thanks. As for all the answers I am getting the following error which must be something to do with the data rather than the query: 'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.'

Comment: Thanks again for your help. The problems I was experiencing were due to some dates defaulting to 1970 when they were imported. Once I removed these from the data I no longer received the error message!

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TEMP') > 0
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE #TEMP
    END
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(BookedDateTime DateTime,
                PickupDateTime DateTime)
INSERT INTO #TEMP
VALUES
('2014-06-09 12:48:00.000', '2014-06-09 12:45:00.000'),
('2014-06-09 12:52:00.000', '2014-06-09 12:58:00.000'), 
('2014-06-10 20:23:00.000', '2014-06-10 20:28:00.000'),
('2014-06-10 22:13:00.000', '2014-06-10 22:13:00.000'),
('2014-06-10 23:59:00.000', '2014-06-11 00:01:00.000')

SELECT CAST(BookedDateTime AS DATE) AS YMDDate,
      CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(second, AVG(DATEDIFF(s, BookedDateTime, PickupDateTime)), 0), 108) [hh:mi:ss],
      CONVERT(CHAR(15), DATEADD(second, AVG(DATEDIFF(s, BookedDateTime, PickupDateTime)), 0), 114) [hh:mi:ss:mmm(24h)]
FROM #TEMP
GROUP BY CAST(BookedDateTime AS DATE)
```

Comment: Many thanks. This works well. As for all the answers I am getting the following error which must be something to do with the data rather than the query: 'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.' I have looked at the dates and I cannot see any that look incorrect though...

Comment: Thanks again for your help. The problems I was experiencing were due to some dates defaulting to 1970 when they were imported. Once I removed these from the data I no longer received the error message!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by finding the difference of each row, summing them up and dividing by the number of rows.

In SQLSERVER it will look like below.

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,BookedDateTime,PickupDateTime)) * 1.0 
           / (SELECT COUNT(*) * 1.0 FROM MyTable)
FROM MyTable
```