# Calculating Average Milliseconds in DateTime Column

Tags: sql

I have a DateTime Column in this format `2019-02-21 11:11:27.743`
The Column `TimeStamp` has many entries.
I'm trying to get the average seconds for the column.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074000/calculate-average-time-difference-between-two-datetime-fields-per-day) and attempted to get the results I need by trying the following.

```
Select Convert(date, Timestamp) as Date, AVG(datediff(MILLISECOND, Timestamp, 
Timestamp)) as AverageTime
from TrackingDetails 
group by Convert(date, Timestamp)  
order by Convert(date, Timestamp)
```

Leaving me with this.

`Date       AverageTime`
`2019-02-21`    `0`

I noticed there is [DateDiff](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp) so with some research I found [TimeDiff](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_timediff.asp)
but that appears to be a MySQL function and not a MSSQL function.

Sample Data
`2019-02-21 11:11:27.743`
`2019-02-21 11:11:57.750`
`2019-02-21 11:12:06.473`
`2019-02-21 11:12:12.817`
`2019-02-21 11:12:17.733`
`2019-02-21 11:12:20.557`
`2019-02-21 11:12:22.533`
`2019-02-21 11:12:24.450`

So far there are `361` entries.

Example of expected result
`Average Time`
`0.01`
or something like that.

Table Structure
`DPID_CODE` `varchar(MAX)`  `Checked`
`RegisteredPost`    `varchar(MAX)`  `Checked` 
`Timestamp` `datetime`  `Checked`

Comment: What does "average seconds" mean?  Can you provide some examples.

Comment: average seconds is what im after for the entire timestamp coloum so the average seconds between a to z

Comment: Please provide some sample data, pasted into the above area.  From that list we can compute the Average(TimeStamp) by adding up all the times and dividing by the number of entries.  To tell us average event moment of the listed rows. But we suspect that is not what you want, when you speak about "average seconds".  So, along with the sample data, please compute what you mean by average seconds.

Comment: As you are comparing the same `AVG(datediff(MILLISECOND, Timestamp, 
Timestamp))` i.e. same `Timestamp` twice, you are getting 0, please provide the table structure and some sample data

Comment: Using the 8 rows of sample data, I get average time of  11:12:08.757.  So is the avg milliseconds  then  757?   Please take 1 or 2 or 8 of the above times, and show us how you would compute an average milliseconds.  Would you add 743 and 750 to get avg of 746.5? etc?  Still having trouble understanding how this average is being used or interpreted.